# grails: show field of object in gsp

Tags: sql, grails, gsp

In my grails project I create instances of an object called Patient, that has got a field city.

```
class Patient {

 String name;
 String surname;
 String cf;
 String address;
 String cap;
 String city;
 String province;
 String country;
 String phone_1;
 String phone_2;
 String email;
 String vat;

}
```

When I create a Patient, I store city by its id, but I want that, in show() and list() methods, I see the name of the related city.

The Cities domain class is linked to a table in my db as follows

```
class Cities {

String cityName;
String capOfCity;
String provinceOfCity;

static constraints = {
}

static mapping = {
    table 's_cap'
    id column: 'idcap'
    cityName column: 'comune'
    capOfCity column: 'cap'
    provinceOfCity column: 'prov'
    version false
}  
}
```

I suppose that I must perform a query to db to get its name by id, but how can I do it in gsp?

Comment: `<div>City: ${patient.city.name}</div>`?

Comment: can you please add the relevant part of the domain classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your current approach you can do

```
def show(){
   // look up your patient object
   def patient = Patient.get(123)
   def patientCityObject = Cities.findByCityName(patient.city)
   [patientCityObject: patientCityObject ]
}
```

GSP:

```
<p>${patientCityObject.cityName}</p>
```

However,

If you define the association between your domains then Grails will load your city when you are accessing it. To access you city object associated with Patient, you can define it as follow:

```
class Patient {
 ...
 Cities city;
 ...

}
```

Then when you have the patient object, you can easily access its property city.

```
def patient = Patient.get(123)
patient.city.cityName
```

This will give you the city object associated with your patient. Then you can pass that into your GSP and use it.

To learn more about GORM and object relation you can read [Object Relational Mapping](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html)

Comment: does this approach works if I only change the type of field city? That's because in Patient creation form, I have a select filled with all cities of the related db table, and after changing the value in select, another field changes with a javascript method

Comment: Changing it to type Cities will store the ID and Grails will load the city object for you.  If you want to have it as string as I mentioned use `findByCityName` to query the database. Both works its just matter of how you want to design your models.

Comment: the first approach must be made into the controller I suppose...but how to do the same in gsp only?

Comment: Is patient.city value the value stored into the db? If yes, it is not the city name but the city ID, so the function it is not findbycityname...so what is the right method to call?

Comment: First which approach you are taking? on your `current approach` `Cities.findByCityName(patient.city)` will give you the city name. I updated my answre

Comment: I've simply done in this way Cities.findById(patientInstance.city).cityName This because patient.city, as said before, is the city id and not the name. I don't use the approach of changing city type from String to Cities because I need to change more things into the form to save the value correctly

Comment: Sure, Usually `ids` are type Long in Grails that was my confusion.